# Proof of $\gcd(an,bn)$=n$\gcd(a,b)$ without using linear combinations.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I was attempting to do this in such way and actually reached a proof, however, i'am not very convinced with the simplicity and the introduction of so many variables, there is it:

Let n be natural, a and b be integers with some d natural being its gcd, so $\gcd(a,b)$ = d $\Rightarrow$ d|a $\land$ d|b $\Rightarrow$ a = dk $\land$ b = dl for some k, l integers $\Rightarrow$ an = dnk $\land$ bn = dnl.

Case 1: $\gcd(an, bn)$ = dn, we are done.

Case 2: $\gcd(an, bn)$ $\neq$ dn, we know dn|an $\land$ dn|bn so, if dn is not its gcd then dn must be less than the actual gcd. Let t be a natural number such that $\gcd(an,bn)$ = t, then an = tp $\land$ bn = ts, for some s, p integers and, since every common divisor divides the gcd, t = dnr, for some r natural $\Rightarrow$ an = dnk = tp = dnrp $\land$ bn = dnl = ts = dnrs $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{an}{dnr}$ = $\frac{a}{dr}$ = p $\land$ $\frac{bn}{dnr}$ = $\frac{b}{dr}$ = s $\Rightarrow$ dr|a $\land$ dr|b, we know r $\neq$ 1 (if not then t = dn, wich is the Case 1) so r $\gt$ 1 $\Rightarrow$ dr $\gt$ d. since dr is a common divisor of a and b and is grater than d it follows that the $\gcd(a,b)$ $\neq$ d, wich is a contradiction, therefore this case cannot happen.

That's it, very simple, but i never saw a proof like this in any textbook (seems they always introduce first linear combinations and other theorems) wich made me wonder if this is okay.

Comment: Use or prove the fact that $\gcd (a,b)$ is the smallest positive number in the set $J = \{ka+mb : k,m \in \matbb{Z}\}$. Or use euclidien algorithm.

Comment: Looks fine to me. This seems like the sensible way to prove it - $\operatorname{gcd}(an,bn) \neq dn$ implies $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b) \neq d$.

Comment: The critical part of your proof is "since every common divisor divides the gcd...". This is of course true, but usually it is proven using Bezout's identity; so if you really insist on avoiding that, you have to prove that any common divisor divides the gcd in some other way. That is totally possible, but using Bezout's identity is probably easier.

Comment: @TimurBakiev that set is not just a linear combination with a and b? Already saw a proof with the euclidien algorithm, but i wanted to use only the fact that every common divisor divides the gcd.

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett didn't notice that, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @sbares i knew that and prove to myself earlier, maybe later i'll post the proof but i remerber is pretty simple too.

Comment: @sebastian this set is an ideal generated by $a$ and $b$, formally speaking. If you know that every common divisor divides the gcd, then you can prove the statement about $J$ easily.

Comment: @sbares Assume a,b,c integers with $\gcd(a,b)$ = d $\land$ c|a,b $\land$ c$\nmid$d. We have a = ck = dp $\land$ b = cl = dt for k, p, l, t integ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{a}{c}$ = $\frac{dp}{c}$ = k $\land$ $\frac{b}{c}$ = $\frac{dt}{c}$ = l $\Leftrightarrow$ c|p $\land$ c|t (since k and l are integer and c$\nmid$d) $\Leftrightarrow$ t = cn $\land$ p = ch, for some c, h integers $\Rightarrow$ a = dp = dch $\land$ b = dcn $\Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{a}{dc}$ = h $\land$ $\frac{b}{dc}$ = n $\Leftrightarrow$ dc|a, b. Since |dc| $\gt$ d it follows that the $\gcd(a,b)$ $\neq$ d, wich is a contradiction.

Comment: @TimurBakiev i'm going to try it then, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @sebastian You cannot generally conclude that if $c$ divides $dp$ and $c$ does not divide $d$ then $c | p$. For example $6$ divides $12 = 3 \cdot 4$, but $6$ does not divide either of $3$ or $4$.

Comment: @sbares i totally forgot about that, my bad, going to try other method then, thanks